# <string, obj> Dictionary to string

Tags: python

I have to fill several objects with data and for this case I've created a dictionary where the key is a number-string and the value is a custom obj

```py
my_dict = {
  '1': my_obj1,
  '2': my_obj2
}
```

my_obj looks like this

```py
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.title = ''
        self.num = 0
        self.name = ''


    def __str__(self):
        return 'title:' + self.title \
               + ', num:' + str(self.num) \
               + ', name:' + self.name
```

The problem is when I try to print it to the console. With `print(my_dict['1'])` I get the an expected output

```
title:here is a title, num:42, name:here is a name
```

but if I try to print the whole dict `print(my_dict)` it doesn't show me the content of Object

```
{'1': <__main__.MyObj object at 0x0000019C02A8E820>, '2': <__main__.MyObj object at 0x0000019C02A83820>}
```

But, why? Why it doesn't call the `__str()__` method if you print the whole dict?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr

Comment: Because `list.__str__` uses the `__repr__` of the objects it contains